# Difference between ～に伴う【ともなう】 and ～を伴う【ともなう】

Tags: grammar

> このしごとはきけん**を伴う**

I am aware of the `にともなう` construct.
Is this any different?
When would ともなう take the を particle rather than に?

Comment: I think it's about time you bought a decent dictionary. They come with example sentences of all common (and many uncommon) word senses and any of the typical grammatical constructions corresponding to them.

Comment: Some of the popular dictionaries are freely available on the Internet. Try [weblio](http://www.weblio.jp/) for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is the object.

“AがBに伴う” = “A accompanies B”

“BがAを伴う” = “B is accompanied by A”

Comment: How about 同伴? Someone remarked to me that 2) example would be more natural with 同伴. Or 同行 Or even ついていく... Should I open a new question?

Comment: @Aki In short, they are not interchangeable. I think you should open a new question.